# Cannot generate images using highcharts-export-server

Tags: json, linux, amazon-web-services, highcharts, apache2.4

I've been trying to generate the charts images to add them to a PDF file.

I am using a Laravel 5.2 web application in a AWS Linux + Apache 2.4 server.

The library `highcharts-export-server` is installed.

In local, the library works fine creating the charts, but when I use it from the server it never creates the image.

The image should be created in `public/plan/chart_images` directory which has 775 permissions.

The command I use is:

```
$command = 'highcharts-export-server -infile '.public_path().'/json/'.$file.'.json -outfile '.public_path().'/plan/chart_images/'.$file.'.png';
exec($command);
Log::info($command);
```

It return the following:

```
[2017-05-17 14:27:33] production.INFO: highcharts-export-server -infile /var/app/current/public/json/47_income_plan.json -outfile /var/app/current/public/plan/chart_images/47_income_plan.png  
[2017-05-17 14:27:33] production.INFO: highcharts-export-server -infile /var/app/current/public/json/47_expense_plan.json -outfile /var/app/current/public/plan/chart_images/47_expense_plan.png  
[2017-05-17 14:27:33] production.INFO: highcharts-export-server -infile /var/app/current/public/json/47_profit_plan.json -outfile /var/app/current/public/plan/chart_images/47_profit_plan.png  
[2017-05-17 14:27:33] production.INFO: highcharts-export-server -infile /var/app/current/public/json/47_projection_plan.json -outfile /var/app/current/public/plan/chart_images/47_projection_plan.png
```

The .json files are generated by another service that writes the .json before executing the command for highchairs chart image generation.

After running this command, there is no error shown and none of the .png files are created in folder: `/var/app/current/public/plan/chart_images`

I also tried running the command myself directly in command line, it runs, shows no error but does not generate any image.

Any help? Thank you guys!

Here is a JSON file I am passing to the command:

```
{
  "chart": {
    "type": "column",
    "backgroundColor": "#FBFBFB",
    "options3d": {
      "enabled": true,
      "alpha": 10,
      "beta": 0,
      "depth": 100
    }
  },
  "colors": ["#5ada29"],
  "title": {
    "text": ""
  },
  "lang": {
    "thousandsSep": ","
  },
  "navigation": {
    "buttonOptions":{
      "enabled": false
    }
  },
  "xAxis": {
    "categories": ["Año 1", "Año 2", "Año 3", "Año 4", "Año 5"]
  },
  "yAxis": {
    "title": {
      "text": this.yAxisTitle,
      "align": "low"
    },
    "stackLabels": {
      "enabled": true,
      "style": {
        "fontWeight": "bold",

      }
    }
  },
  "legend": {
    "enabled": false
  },
  "tooltip": {
    "pointFormat": "$<b>{point.y}</b>"
  },
  "plotOptions": {
    "column": {
      "stacking": "normal"
    }
  },

  "credits": {
    "enabled": false
  },
  "series": [{
    "name": "Population",
    "data": [[1,645586],[2,1264953],[3,1590373],[4,1854675],[5,2120331]]
  }]
}
```

Here is a log where is print the command to be executed and its immediate response using the `--logLevel 4` option:

```
[2017-05-18 17:56:16] local.INFO: Command: '/usr/local/bin/highcharts-export-server -infile json/39_income_plan.json -outfile plan/chart_images/39_income_plan.png --logLevel 4'  
[2017-05-18 17:56:16] local.INFO: Response:   
[2017-05-18 17:56:16] local.INFO: Command: '/usr/local/bin/highcharts-export-server -infile json/39_expense_plan.json -outfile plan/chart_images/39_expense_plan.png --logLevel 4'  
[2017-05-18 17:56:16] local.INFO: Response:   
[2017-05-18 17:56:16] local.INFO: Command: '/usr/local/bin/highcharts-export-server -infile json/39_profit_plan.json -outfile plan/chart_images/39_profit_plan.png --logLevel 4'  
[2017-05-18 17:56:16] local.INFO: Response:   
[2017-05-18 17:56:16] local.INFO: Command: '/usr/local/bin/highcharts-export-server -infile json/39_projection_plan.json -outfile plan/chart_images/39_projection_plan.png --logLevel 4'  
[2017-05-18 17:56:16] local.INFO: Response:
```

Comment: Could you please simplify the example, try to run a pure highcharts-export-server -infile someJsonFile.json -outfile someImageFile.png and display what the JSON file looks like

Comment: add also --logLevel 4 to the command to see what is not working

Comment: Can you paste a sample chart config from the json?

Comment: @morganfree I edited my answer.

Comment: @MustaphaMekhatria I added what it returns using --logLeve 4 to my answer.

Comment: It does not like a correct json. Try to replace "this.yAxisTitle" with some string or remove this part.

Comment: @morganfree I did this and still happening, the problem is not the JSON, actually tried with the most simple case. The problem is that it does not generate the images.

Comment: @morganfree actually, added to the very simple syntax I am talking about the code that is "wrong" and it generated the chart in my local, still not the chart in the server

Comment: Maybe, it is the issue with the paths. Can you make sure that they are correct?